# BlackBerry - height of available screen excluding banner & title fields

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, screen

I would like to know how much vertical real estate is available to my manager on a screen (without scrolling).

I would like to have this manager in a separate class, not in the Screen subclass. Ideally, my manager would be able to be placed on any screen, without any knowledge of the screen specifics being passed to it - this manager would be able to find out how much space has been left unused by the Screen's title / banner fields.

I can get the screen size with many methods. That is the easy part. But it does not take account of title / banner fields.

What I would like to know is how to find the part of the screen that is not covered by any title or banner fields? But I would like to have a general solution, that can be used in a separate class file, with no prior knowledge of the screen it is to be displayed on.

(workaround: I would have to tell my manager what the height of the title / banner fields was, and then I could use these heights, with `Display.getHeight()` to calculate the available space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a separate class (call it `CobiPainter`) which is able to be used by any manager or screen class - it implements one method which I have called `paintBackground(Graphics g)`. I call this method from within any related `paintBackground(Graphics g)` override of the screen whose background I want to paint.

In order to be able to be used by any `MainScreen`, with minimal coupling & extra work, I have made it so that the `CobiPainter` class is able to calculate how much screen is available, without needing to be given any knowledge of the title / banner / status fields.

The code I have used relies on the fact that the `MainScreen` has an internal manager to which we normally add the fields. This manager knows the height that I am looking for.

This is the hack/code I used:

```
Screen activeScreen = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen();
if (activeScreen instanceof MainScreen)
{
    // get available height excluding banner / title
    XYRect xy = ((MainScreen) activeScreen).getMainManager()
        .getExtent();
    heightOfTitleAndBanner = xy.y;  // <---- can be useful too
    availableHeight = xy.height;    // <---- this is what I wanted
}
```

This code will not work until the manager in question is displayed, since it relies on calling the `getActiveScreen()` method. It also requires that the `MainScreen` was created with the parameter `Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL` to force it to take the screen's size (thanks to Himanshu).

Answer (score 0):

There are three fieldmanager like-VerticalFieldManager,HorizontalFieldManager  and FlowFieldManager which can be set with Non-Scrollable,vertically as well as Horizontally. 
You have to create an object for the Horizontal/Vertical FieldManager with the parameter (Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL|Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL)

But you have to customize it to fulfill your conditions.

If you want to know the title size then simply add the containt in the Horizontal/Vertical FieldManager and get its height or width using getPreferedHeight() and  getPreferedWidth() respectivelly.

Here is rought code :

```
final LabelField field  = new LabelField("Himanshu")
        {
            protected void layout(int width, int height) 
            {
                super.layout(width, height);
//              setExtent(360, 50);
            };
            public int getPreferredHeight() 
            {
                return super.getPreferredHeight();
            }
        };
        final LabelField field1  = new LabelField("Himanshu")
        {
            protected void layout(int width, int height) 
            {
                super.layout(width, height);
//              setExtent(360, 50);
            };
            public int getPreferredHeight() 
            {
                return super.getPreferredHeight();
            }
        };
        setTitle(field);
        setStatus(field1);
        VerticalFieldManager fieldManager = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH|Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL)
        {
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) 
            {
                super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
                this.setExtent(360, Display.getHeight()-(field.getPreferredHeight())-(field1.getPreferredHeight()));
            }
        };
        fieldManager.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLUE));
        System.out.println("-------------"+field.getPreferredHeight());
        add(fieldManager);
```

Comment: No, i added comment on that particular line , here i am getting the height of field 20 px, using field.getPrefferedHeight().U should check it

Comment: thx - I am still unable to get it to function the way I want - perhaps I have not explained very well. I have again updated the question to specify that I am looking for an answer that can be used from a separate class, which has no prior knowledge of the banner / title fields. Ideally my code would not need references to the title fields. Your `fieldManager` knows about `field` and `field1` - this is the workaround that I am trying to avoid (if at all possible).

Answer (score 0):

What I do is a kind of a workaround of system's inability to provide that information.

1) Extend all your screens from a BaseScreen class.
2) When setting the Banner (setBanner()) in that class store the instance of the banner you put in. Example:

```
public abstract class BaseScreen extends MainScreen
{
    private StandardTitleBar titleBar;

    ...    // some initializer body, i.e. constructor
        titleBar = getStandardTitleBar();
        setBanner(titleBar);
    ...
}
```

3) Expose the height/width of the set banner in your BaseScreen class

```
public int getBannerHeight()
{
    if (null == titleBar)
        return 0;
    else
        return titleBar.getHeight();
}
```

4) inside protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) of your manager use:

```
int bannerHeight = ((BaseScreen) getScreen()).getBannerHeight();
int titleHeight  = getScreen().getTitleBar().getHeight() // TODO: protect from null
```

In my experience, I also account for the Virtual Keyboard and manager's padding when necessary.